# Extremely slow network directory subfolder listing from QNAP NAS in OS X

Tags: macos, nas, samba, smb

Having an issue where I have a folder on a QNAP NAS (TS-439P II+) with over 68,000 subfolders within it.

**I can browse it quickly and almost instantaneously within Windows 7 via samba**, however in OSX 10.6.8, it takes nearly 10+ minutes to display the subfolders, using both samba and AFP.

Hoping there is an easy solution - we can't break the folders into smaller subfolders due to a requirement of proprietary software that accesses the sub folders.

I've tried the fixes suggested here, which don't seem to help:
http://www.macwindows.com/snowleopard-filesharing.html#030311b

Comment: I have been getting slow access on my QNAP NAS with OS X as well, but only through SMB. AFP seemed to be very fast. As a workaround, you could maybe SFTP-mount it?

Comment: This happens when also browsing to an SMB share on a Windows 2003 server - so it's likely an OS X or Finder issue.  Seems that Finder is trying to cache the folders before displaying them, while Windows displays them immediately.

Answer (score -1):

As stated above this is an issue with finder. As a test try using terminal to browse and see if this is any quicker, you will probably find it is. There is no quick fix as far as I'm aware although searching through macwindows.com and trying the various fixes is the best place to start.